# How to change action window for menuitem?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

In odoo, I want to change the action window of default menuitem. As I can not do changes in default module, I have created other menuitem but it is showing both default and new menuitem. I have tried for inheriting action window also but it didnt worked for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the answer to inherit the menuitem..

```
<record model="ir.ui.menu" id="module_name.original_menu">
    <field name="action" ref="new_action_id"/>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide original menuitem and create new one with same sequence and parent.

Easy as eating ice-cream ;)

Comment: You can also make it with bad way I think... by using original id as menuitem id. e.g `base.menuitem_id`, but Odoo doesn't likes it.

Comment: How to hide original menuitem?

Comment: Create dummy_group and add this group to this menuitem, so nobody will be able to see it, even administrators